# Is it possible to open a new chrome Browser Window from Terminal with multiple screens?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, google-chrome

I am working on multiple screens on macOS. When I intend to open a new chrome window (not a tab), I have to press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to shift focus from another app to the current browser app and activate the new window menu by keying <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

If input command

```
open https://apple.stackexchange.com
```

A new tab created not a new window.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
open -na "Google Chrome" --args --new-window "https://georgegarside.com"
```

`-n` opens a new instance of an application. Google Chrome detects this and remedies the situation by closing the new instance and passing the tab’s location to the first instance, but this is necessary to force arguments to be read.
`--args` indicates what's to follow are arguments to be passed to Google Chrome, not `open`.
`--new-window` is a Google Chrome argument to force a new window to be created.